# javascript copy div change innerHTML id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to copy content from one div to another one with changing button's id (increment them)

Sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function add(){
    document.getElementById('two').innerHTML = document.getElementById('one').innerHTML;
  }
</script>

<div id="one">
  <button id="button_1" >Button_1</button>
</div>

<div id="two"></div>

<button onclick="add();">Add</button>
```

This of course can't work properly.

Result should be following:

```
<div id="two">
  <button id="button_2" >Button_2</button>
</div>
```

Any simple way how to do this ?

Comment: How many times do you need to do this? Can you store the number of divs you currently have and just increment that?

Comment: "Cloning" will be starting from 2, ends up with X with for loop, i think the solution for this will be slice() function, where number++, will be added to end of id and button text. Everytime it should create a new div (two,three,...) with new button in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made small change in 'id' of the wrapping div.

```
     <div id="1" class="button">
        <button id="button_1" >Button_1</button>
    </div>

   <button onclick="add();">Add</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function add(){
            var count = document.querySelectorAll('.button').length;
            var newCount = count+1;
            var elDiv = document.createElement('div');
            elDiv.setAttribute("id", newCount);
            elDiv.setAttribute("class", "button");
            elDiv.innerHTML = '<button id="button_"+newCount+">Button_'+newCount+"</button>";

            document.getElementById(count).appendChild(elDiv);
        }
    </script>
```

However it can be done in more simpler way using jQuery. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want copy the button onclick of a button it will work for you i guess..

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;


var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('one');

function duplicate() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "one" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
    <button id="button_1" >Button_1</button>
</div>


<button id="button" style="color:red">Add</button>
```

Comment: buttons id will increment by one on every click of a button. Id's will be one1, one2 ....

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this. With a good mastery of jQuery traversal you may not even need to give each button an id. May be a common class may serve you well.

```js
$(function() {
    var last = $('.container');
    var curr = last;
    
    $('#add').on('click', function() {
        last = curr.clone();
        last.find('button').attr('id', function() {
            return 'button_' + ( $('div.container').length + 1 );
        })
        .html(function() {
            return 'Button_' + ( $('div.container').length + 1 );
        }).end()
        .insertAfter( curr );
        curr = last;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <button id="button_1" >Button_1</button>
</div>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```
function add( fromId, toId ){
    content = $('#'+fromId).clone();
    button = content.find('button');
    if( button.length == 1 ){
        buttonId = button.attr('id');
        number = buttonId.match(/\d+/g);
        number = parseInt(number[0]) + 1;
        button.attr('id','button_' + number);
        button.html('Button_' + number);
    }
    $('#'+toId).html(content.html());
}
```

Just call

```
add('one','two');
```